# How to detect uninstall using FCM on IOS?

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

## TL;DR

I'm detecting uninstalls using FCM. If I receive a `NotRegistered token` on sending notification, I assume that the app has been uninstalled.

Everything works fine with Android, while on IOS I'm always getting a `success` response, even if the app has uninstalled for days.

## More info

I have [read](https://clevertap.com/blog/track-app-uninstalls-effectively/) that it is possible to detect uninstalls using `APNs feedback Service`, where Apple reports any inactive tokens.

Also I read on Firebase official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) that:

> content_available - On iOS, use this field to represent content-available in the APNs payload. When a notification or message is sent and this is set to true, an inactive client app is awoken, and the message is sent through APNs as a silent notification and not through the FCM connection server.

In order to send notifications via APN, I have tried to send push notifications using `content_available: true`, but I cannot reproduce a `NotRegistered token` error on IOS. It still returns a `success` message.

I'm sending notifications using `sendMulticast`. my payload:

```
const payload = {
  notification: {
      title: text,
  },
  android: {
      priority: "high",
      ttl: 60 * 60 * 1,
      collapseKey: "yo",
      notification: {
          channel_id: 'YO',
          tag: userDoc.id,
      },
  },
  apns: {
      payload: {
          aps: {
              sound: "reminder.caf",
              "content-available": 1,
          }
      },
      headers: {
          "apns-collapse-id": "yo",
          "apns-priority": "10"
      }
  },
  priority: 10
}
```

I also cannot reproduce a `NotRegistered token` response via an HTTP request:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
  -H 'authorization: key=server_key_here' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "to": "fcm_token_here", 
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "notification": {
    "empty": "body"
  },
  "data": {
    "key1": ""
  }
}'
```

## Bottom Line

**1. How do I detect IOS uninstalls using FCM?

2. And if it's not possible, how can I detect uninstalls on IOS?**

Comment: I'm having the same issue after referencing the same resources. Did you ever find out how to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing yet :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends on your demand. Your questions's answer is **slient push** not normal push.

A background notification is a remote notification that doesn’t display an alert, play a sound, or badge your app’s icon. It wakes your app in the background and gives it time to initiate downloads from your server and update its content. [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app)

---

**Important**

> The system treats background notifications as low priority: you can use them to refresh your app’s content, but the system ***doesn’t guarantee*** their delivery. In addition, the system may throttle the delivery of background notifications if the total number becomes excessive. The number of background notifications allowed by the system depends on current conditions, but don’t try to send more than two or three per hour.
>
> Silent push notifications will not work when the device is in “Low
> Data Mode“.

Slient Push Notification Payload Example.

```
  {
   "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1
   },
   "acme1" : "bar",
   "acme2" : 42
}
```

You have to use ***"content-available" : 1*** in payload for **slient push**.

On the other hand, if your client running on iOS 12.3 or later [Deletions metric](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=iosdeletions)

Comment: Gursrs thanks for replying. I have already mentioned `content-available` background messaging in my question. The problem is that I cannot reproduce `notRegitered` response on uninstalled app. Do you know why is it happening? Did you ever got `notRegistered` response using FCM through IOS devices?